# RenderAction Partial View is Caching on Back Button Asp.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a div with a Partial View on it which i render using RenderAction().
I am using Asp.Net MVC 4.0.

My problem is and it happens only on IE(version 9) , when i go to some other page and click the back button on IE, the partial view is not rendered. The partial View section is blank. Even on Firefox, the Action is not called, but at least the Partial View is rendered (its not blank)

Is there any solution to this ?

**UPDATE**

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {    
         <article style="margin-top: 10px;">
             <h5>
                 @item.Title
             </h5>
             <span >
                 <time>
                     @item.FromDateMonth
                 </time>-
             <time>
                 @item.ToDateMonth
             </time>
             </span>
             <div style="margin-top:10px;">
                 @Html.Label("Notes:", new { @style = "color: #000000; font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 16px;" })
                 <span style="color: #000000; font-size: 13px; font-weight: normal; line-height: 16px;">
                     @item.Notes
                 </span>
             </div>

         </article>
```

Comment: Typically, the back button on browsers just shows what it did previously. It depends on what your partial looks like. What is it outputting?

Comment: I have updated with the html.. Thanks